# Orthographe : Angers et Anjou

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, histoire, toponymes

Chaque fois que je vois une carte de France, je me demande : pourquoi An**g**ers et An**j**ou (et non *Anjers ni *Angeou) ?

Selon [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angers#Le_nom_d'Angers),

> Angers est mentionnée au Moyen Âge sous les formes *Andecava civitas* au VIe siècle et *Andecavis* en 769, *Andegavis* entre 861 et 882, *Angieus* en 1127, *Angeus* en 1205 et *Angiers* dès le XIIe siècle.

Donc le c devient un g, et après le départ du d, *Andecavis* a donné 'Angers'.

L'explication (*in extenso*) d'Anjou est beaucoup moins limpide :

> La variante *Andecavum* explique le nom d'Anjou (*in Andecavo* en 797).

Comment: Je suggère que tu reformules ta question en partant de ce paragraphe de Wikipedia [Le nom d'Angers](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angers#Le_nom_d'Angers) qui explique le passage du nom latin de *Andecavorum* à Angers et la variante *Andecavum* qui explique le nom d'Anjou, en disant ce que tu ne comprends pas pour que la réponse soit plus adaptée. Sinon je veux bien recopier le passage de wikipedia ici mais je ne pense pas que ça nous avance beaucoup.

Comment: @Laure C'est un bon début mais "*La variante Andecavum explique le nom d'Anjou*" ne suffit pas à expliquer d'où vient le son \ʒ\ et surtout pourquoi il y a deux orthographes différentes.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je n'ai pas dit que c'était la réponse mais pour moi la question était mal posée (tu as certainement vu qu'elle a été modifiée depuis que j'avais fait mon commentaire). Ce que veut savoir le PO c'est, entre autres, qu'on lui explique « la lénition des consonnes intervocaliques » qui a fait que *Andecavis* est devenu  *Angeus* puis Angers. Et comment *Andecavum* est devenu  *Anjou*.

Answer (score 1):

[francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-39624.php](http://francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-39624.php)

Ce lien explique les différentes prononciations de la lettre G devant une voyelle

Et afin d'éviter d'écrire **Angeou**, le G a été remplacé par un J, afin de donner **Anjou**

J'espère que cela répond à ta question.

Comment: En suivant le lien donnné dans la question on peut constater que ce n'est pas la réponse qui repose sur l'étymologie. On peut aussi tenir compte de cette remarque : [Angers peut se targuer d'avoir une étymologie qui fait consensus chez les historiens](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/05/10/37003-20170510ARTFIG00012-angers-d-o-vient-ton-nom.php).

Comment: @Laure : à propos de ton lien ci-dessus : Un bulletin de la Société d'Agriculture Sciences et Arts d'Angers de 1853 observe effectivement... mais non sans surprise ce consensus apparent étant donné la demi-douzaine de possibilités toutes aussi critiquables les unes que les autres...